# how to bold a text which is on <strong> tag in blackberry

Tags: web-services, blackberry

I've got HTML string returned from a Web Service. Sample string would be:

[image: sample string]

I want to display the HTML string in the label field.

I've replaced the string `<b>`, `<br/>` to `</n>`. Its fine.

I want to set bold the string which is on `<strong>`, `</strong>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you want to make all the text bold, just use:

```
yourLabelField.setFont(getFont().derive(Font.BOLD, getFont().getHeight()));
```

If you want only a part of the text, you will have to use RichTextField:

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/3.7api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/RichTextField.html

Comment: hi frnd., thank u for your info. do u've sample code for changes only part of the text...

Comment: Man use the RichTextField and try the sample codes with it than you will be able to color a part of the text

Answer (score 0):

in many tags are not working in label field so if you want to display according to HTML tags you need to use Browser Field like

```
String str="<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">a {color:OLIVE;}</style></head><body style=background-image:url('local:///background.png');background-repeat:no-repeat; width:100%;height:100%;> <font size=3 color=olive><b>About Us</b></font> <font size=2>"what the string do you want to show hear you can paste"</body></html>";
    browser_field.displayContent(str,"");
```

Comment: Friend., But browser field support from 5.0 only. Thats to i replace and display on lablefield.